Question on iterated fixed points of $x^2-2$
Let $P(x)=x^2-2$. Let $P_n(x)$ denote the $n^{th}$ iteration of P. I was asked to prove that the equation $P_n(x)=x$ has all distinct real roots.
My attempt:
I tried using induction, but I'm not sure if -1 and 2 (the 2 roots of P) have distinct $n^{th}$ preimages i.e. if $P_n(x)=-1$ or 2 has $2^n$ distinct real roots, so I'm stuck.
I also tried using IVT to find a 3-cycle on the 3rd iteration, so by Lee-yorke theorem we know it contains a cycle of every length, and these n-cycles surely are the roots of $P_n(x)=x$, but thats nowhere near $2^n$ potential number of roots; I am not sure what I am missing.
Any help would be appreciated!

Not necessarily much easier, but one different angle to approach the problem from: you can try taking $\gcd(P_n(x)-x, P'_n(x)-1)$ and show that it's $1$ to prove that there are no repeated roots, and by checking sign changes along the way possibly show that all the roots are real via Sturm's theorem. I haven't gone through this, but I feel like going through the first few instances might provide some insight as to how to prove. Keep in mind the recursive formula for the derivative of an iterated function.

This is sort of a trick question. Here is a large hint: what happens when you substitute $x = 2 \cos \theta$?

I think the angle doubles. That means I can get whatever roots by taking multiples of $cos(\pi/(2^n-1))$, and with the original roots -1 and 2 we're done right? Thanks!
